# jQuery delay between each toggleclass

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, toggleclass

I have made a (rather complicated) solution where I have 4 menu items pop in/out from the side and I make that happen by toggling a class.

```
$('.menuitem').toggleClass('show');
```

It works great but the client now wants it to "slide out". I figured that I can make him happy if I can create a delay between each toggle, but I cant find a good way to do it. In practice I want each menu item to toggleClass but with a delay of maybe 250ms before next toggleClass.

Edited - Apparently the delay function wont work with toggle, only with animations.

Comment: Seems like an XY problem in absence of details. What is the `show` class doing? What do you mean by *pop in/out*? How would adding a delay cause it to suddenly *slide-out*?

Comment: Seems like a simple question should stay simple. Anyway, I got the right answer from Manwal

Comment: Fair enough Paul. Good that you found your solution. You may want to accept the answer if you found it useful. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this following code:

```
$('.menuitem').each(function(i) { 
    var elm=$(this);
    setTimeout(function() { 
        elm.toggleClass('show');
    }, i * 250); 
});
```

[**See it in action**](http://jsfiddle.net/fph9ov1s/), in this demo i have hiding diving one by one and delay is 1000 ms.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
$('.menuitem').toggleClass('show').delay(1000).toggleClass('hide');
```

See [jQuery's delay() function](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) for further reference.

Comment: delay wont work with toggleClass, apparently it only works with animations

Comment: @Paul I did not know that, my mistake.

Comment: You need to put code in queue in order to use delay() and anyway, will work on all set of elements at once

Answer (score 0):

I would do the `$('.menuitem').toggleClass('show')` in a separate event.

For instance `<button onmousedown="$('.menuitem').toggleClass('show');" onclick="myfunc();">Fast Toggle</button>`

If you toggle onmousedown the page will render with the toggle before the click event fires.